# Update table with two columns as unique constraints in SQLite, NOT create table again

Tags: database, sqlite, alter-table, unique-key

I want to update table in my `SQLite` database and add `UNIQUE` contraint to two columns in my *Data* table.

Here is what I was trying , but throws error.

```
ALTER TABLE Data
ADD CONSTRAINT Data UNIQUE(id, dateofday);
```

All previous answers are on *create table* which I don't want. Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It is not possible**.You cannot add a constraint to an existing table in sqlite. You can only rename table or add columns to a table.

Link for your reference : http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

**However you can use this alternate approach to achieve the same.**

1. Create a temporary table with the same columns as your current table with all the constraints you need.
2. Then move all the data from the old table to the new temporary table with constraints defined using
   `INSERT INTO Destination SELECT * FROM Source;`
3. Check if you have copied all the data from the original table to temporary table.
4. Drop your original table and rename the temporary table to the name of the original table.

Comment: ohh :( . Which is why this question didn't exist here before! I don't wan't to loose my data. But I will have to do it anyways it means .Thank You +1